# Bulk Update Products NotWorking when using Woocommerce API

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Today I'm working with woo and testing an endpoint before using it on the code, i found an issue.
I'm not sure if it is a bug or I'm missing something.

Following the [Documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#batch-update-products) I built a request with postman using basic auth.

I expect to update the product with the new data but, I cannot see the changes on the page or dashboard.

This is the CURL generateed by postman:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/batch' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic Y2tfODIzN2FiNmNkYmMzNzBkMjc4NDE5MDc2MGUxNGMzNjQ3N2ZkMTZiNTpjc184ZDYwZjAyMDRlMTNmYmEzMzE1ZGU1YWJhY2E2NzdmODZjMDAwOGZm' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: wfwaf-authcookie-803a107cc52319e56ba148a20b0128e0=1572%7C%7Cb5721804b1a748e2798b3b3d10a4055e4f4c0fc5cdee5d7ceb87d543c09fc722' \
--data-raw '{
  "update": [
    {
      "id": 24552,
      "name": "Product",
      "permalink": "https://example.com/producto/product-link/",
      "status": "publish",
      "sku": "MALV-SKU-1",
      "price": 87.00,
      "regular_price": 0,
      "sale_price": 0
    }
  ]
}'
```

The response is a biiiiig portion of text. But i can summarize that it returns 200, ok and the requested body.

Any Idea to fix it?

Note: credentials are running because I use the same with the GET verb and it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue Here was that i was trying to update the price of a product with variations.
I tested the same code with a non variations product and worked successfully.

In case of products with variations, these are who place the price.